# Subset dataframe based on previous accepted row

Tags: r

Hi I have a dataframe as below and i wanted to be able to subset the dataframe so only the ones in the result data frame are left. I would like 3 rules

1. If starT is after the previous rows StarT and before the previous rows EndT then that row is removed
2. If StarT is between the previous rows starT and EndT but even if that EndT is after the previous rows EndT its still removed
3. If starT is after both previous row StarT and EndT but within 10 of the previous rows EndT then it is removed.

It also needs to always refer to the last row that was kept in the dataframe.

```
 StarT    EndT  Alarmcode 
1 3297.58 3298.62  13902 
2 3297.60 3346.20  13907 
3 3297.62 3346.17  14111 
4 3297.78 3346.13  13909 
5 3298.65 3346.08  13908 
6 3298.70 3298.75  13902 
7 3298.83 3298.88  13902 
8 3298.97 3298.98  13902 
9 3298.98 3346.03  13900 
10 3299.07 3346.00 13902 
11 3344.07 3352.75  1001 
12 3344.48 3345.90 13906 
13 3345.47 3345.87 15111 
14 3345.87 3347.78 15111 
15 3345.92 3346.58 13906 
16 3346.12 3346.17 13902 
17 3346.23 3346.50 13908 
18 3346.25 3346.30 13902 
19 3346.27 3347.75 14111 
20 3346.38 3346.43 13902 
21 3346.52 3346.53 13902 
22 3346.53 3347.70 13900 
23 3346.58 3347.67 13908 
24 3346.60 3347.63 13906 
25 3346.62 3347.60 13902 
26 3347.65 3352.30 13906 
27 3347.70 3347.72 13902 
28 3347.80 3352.25 13908 
29 3347.80 3352.27 15111 
30 3347.80 3352.28 14111 
31 3347.80 3347.85 13902 
32 3347.93 3347.98 13902 
33 3348.07 3348.12 13902 
34 3348.20 3348.22 13902 
35 3348.22 3352.23 13900 
36 3348.30 3352.00 13902 
37 3349.27 3352.22  13907 
38 14157.28 14157.28 5122 
39 27311.37 27311.38 5122
```

should be left with this:

```
       StarT EndT  Alarmcode 
1 3297.58 3298.62  13902 
38 14157.28 14157.28 5122 
39 27311.37 27311.38 5122
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do above with `lag` and `lead` functions from `dplyr`.
I don't quite understand your rules very well...but I will try to give you the general idea so you can fit your rules as you understand to the code.

Essentially, using `lag` you can refer to the previous row. Then you can create logic statements using `>` or `<` using your rules.

You can then directly remove those rows who don't fit the criteria using `filter` function. Note that this will change the order of your rows since they are removed before moving on to the next rule. To work around this, you can create a column that checks your rule status, using `mutate` and only apply `filter` at the end of your rule logics.

So here is how it works:

> If starT is after the previous rows StarT and before the previous rows EndT then that row  is removed

```
df <- df %>%
  mutate(rule = ifelse(StarT > lag(StarT, 1) & StarT < lag(EndT, 1), 'remove', 'keep'))
```

> If StarT is between the previous rows starT and EndT but even if that EndT is after the previous rows EndT its still removed

I don't understand this one, sorry. Sounds the same as the first?

> If starT is after both previous row StarT and EndT but within 10 of the previous rows EndT then it is removed.

```
df <- df %>%
  mutate(rule = ifelse(StarT > lag(EndT, 1) + 10, 'remove', rule))
```

Then at the end you can go:

```
df <- df %>%
filter(rule != 'remove') %>%  # this filters out any rows that fit remove rules above
select(-rule) ## this remove the rule column
```

Hope this helps.
Otherwise, happy to write the full code if you could clarify your second rule.

Comment: the second one you dont understand so if one alarm started at 100min and ended 110 min and the next one started 105 but ended 115 (starts within the time of the previous alarm but ends after) i would like to also remove it.

Comment: Isn't that covered by the first rule? Your first rule states if start time is between the previous start and end it is removed.